# Xamarin Webview with form scrolls out of view when clicking textbox

Tags: html, xamarin, webview

Using a webview to load a simple html form, the form displays ok. 
When clicking an input field the entire form disappears showing arrows up and down and done button at bottom part of display. This behavior does not happen in a normal Chrome browser. Any idéas?

Best regards
Andreas

Xaml:

```
            <WebView Grid.Row="0" IsEnabled="false" 
                    x:Name="webview"  
                Navigating="webViewNavigating"></WebView>

        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Byt Betalsätt" Activated="BtnBack_Clicked" Priority="0" Order="Primary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

</ContentPage>
```

HTML:

```
  <!-- New section -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Fill in your publishable key
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_1GitP47uZiwo4PKrDDSo8P3X');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="/your-charge-code" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month">
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Billing Postal Code</span>
      <input type="text" size="6" data-stripe="address_zip">
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Can I ask why your Webview is in a Grid? Can you take it out of the Grid and see if there's any change? Also IsEnabled="false" might be case sensitive and the XAML might not like it, change to  IsEnabled="False" (Capital f)

Comment: Which platform? iOS? Android? Both? When clicking an input element, the keyboard should show and should have the arrow buttons to navigate between form fields and the Done button to dismiss the keyboard. Are you seeing a full keyboard when you click the input field?

Comment: stepheaw: just an attempt to fix the problem, same result without Grid and same result when removing IsEnabled attribute.

Comment: jgoldberger: IOS, there's no keyboard visible when I click the input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd, so I made a web page using your HTML code, and then created a new Xamarin.Forms solution with a `WebView` pointing to the page I created from your HTML. When I clicked any of the input fields the soft keyboard showed as expected. However if I made sure the `WebView` was at the bottom of the screen, under where the keyboard shows, the keyboard does hide the `WebView`. To fix this, you would need a custom page renderer [1] to scroll the view up when the keyboard shows up and scroll the view back down when the keyboard goes away.

Here is some sample code to do this. I assume you would only want to do this on pages that have that `WebView`, so first in the Forms PCL project create an empty subclass of `ContentPage` called `WebViewContentPage`:

```
public class WebViewContentPage : ContentPage {}
```

Then you inherit from the `WebViewContentPage` for the actual page that has the `WebView`, in my test I called it `TestWebInputPage`:

```
public partial class TestWebInputPage : WebViewContentPage
{ 
    public TestWebInputPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My Xaml is (change UrlToWebPageHere to the actual url of your web page):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:WebViewContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWebInput" x:Class="TestWebInput.TestWebInputPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Take up space" 
            HeightRequest="400" />
        <WebView 
            x:Name="webView" 
            Navigating="Handle_Navigating" 
            Source="UrlToWebPageHere" 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</local:WebViewContentPage>
```

And finally the custom page renderer code. This goes in the iOS app project:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using TestWebInput.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using TestWebInput;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebViewContentPage), typeof(ContentPageRenderer))]
namespace TestWebInput.iOS
{
    public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {   
        private NSObject keyBoardWillShow;
        private NSObject keyBoardWillHide;
        private nfloat scrollAmout;
        private double animDuration;
        private UIViewAnimationCurve animCurve;
        private bool keyboardShowing;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            base.ViewDidLoad();

            keyBoardWillShow = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillShow(KeyboardWillShow);

            keyBoardWillHide = UIKeyboard.Notifications.ObserveWillHide(KeyboardWillHide);
        }

        void KeyboardWillShow(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!keyboardShowing)
            {
                keyboardShowing = true;
                animDuration = args.AnimationDuration;
                animCurve = args.AnimationCurve;

                var r = UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(args.Notification);
                scrollAmout = r.Height;
                ScrollTheView(true);
            }
        }

        void KeyboardWillHide(object sender, UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (keyboardShowing)
            {
                keyboardShowing = false;
                animDuration = args.AnimationDuration;
                animCurve = args.AnimationCurve;

                var r = UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(args.Notification);
                scrollAmout = r.Height;
                ScrollTheView(false);
            }
        }

        private void ScrollTheView(bool scale)
        {
            UIView.BeginAnimations(string.Empty, IntPtr.Zero);
            UIView.SetAnimationDuration(animDuration);
            UIView.SetAnimationCurve(animCurve);

            var frame = View.Frame;

            if (scale)
                frame.Y -= scrollAmout;
            else
                frame.Y += scrollAmout;
            View.Frame = frame;
            UIView.CommitAnimations();
        }
    }
}
```

Since this renderer actually scrolls the entire native page up and back down when the keyboard shows and hides, it should not matter how you layout the page in the Forms Xaml. All that matters is that your Forms page inherits from `WebViewContentPage`.

I hope this helps!

[1] https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/

Comment: wow this is advanced, thanks for taking the time, will try it tonight,

Comment: it works, it still moves page, I guess tuning in "Take up space" label. Thanks!