# Webview text field gets scrolled to top when trying to focus - Xamarin.forms iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have xamarin forms iOS app contains a webview. The webview load a html page contains some text fields.The problem I am facing is whenever we click on the text field,the keyboard shows and the entire web page will scroll to top and the text field will become invisible.When we open the same page on a browser it works fine. I have used `xam.plugins.forms.keyboard overlap` for my other non webview pages. How can I fix this issue? I want the textview field should be there when we focus it .

I have seen this similar problem on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251036/xamarin-webview-with-form-scrolls-out-of-view-when-clicking-textbox). But it didn't solved my issue. Any help is appreciated.

**My XAML**

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <WebView x:Name="Webview"  
             HeightRequest="1000"  
             WidthRequest="1000"  
             IsVisible="False"
             Navigating="OnNavigating"  
             Navigated="OnNavigated"  
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Can you try whether it works if you don't use the xam.plugins.forms.keyboard overlap?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Thanks bro.. the plugin caused the issue. But how can I solve the keyboard overlapping issue solved by the plugin? what can be the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the plugin and implement it by yourself.

For example, you can check the [source code](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/blob/master/KeyboardOverlap/KeyboardOverlap/KeyboardOverlap.Forms.Plugin.iOSUnified/KeyboardOverlapRenderer.cs) and copy it to your project as a PageRenderer.

In the page renderer, I add a bool value to check whether you need to use this renderer or not. Here I use the ClassId to check:

```
bool useThisRenderer;

protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        Page p = e.NewElement as Page;

        if (p.ClassId == "0")
        {
            useThisRenderer = false;
        }
        else
        {
            useThisRenderer = true;
        }
    }
    
}

public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    if (useThisRenderer)
    {
        var page = Element as ContentPage;

        if (page != null)
        {
            var contentScrollView = page.Content as ScrollView;

            if (contentScrollView != null)
                return;

            RegisterForKeyboardNotifications();
        }
    }
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

    if (useThisRenderer)
    {
        UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications();
    }
}
```

Then in your Xamarin.forms project, if one of your content page does not need this renderer(for example the current page you have a webview), you can set the `classid = "0"` to avoid this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.ClassId = "0";
}
```

If you need this renderer, then do nothing about this.ClassId.

I upload a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/keyboard-iOS) and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Hi, When try to implement PageRender class, I get an error at this line var activeView = View.FindFirstResponder();

Comment: It says, UIView does not contain a defenition for FindFirstRsponder();

Comment: @Anand You need too add [this class](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/blob/master/KeyboardOverlap/KeyboardOverlap/KeyboardOverlap.Forms.Plugin.iOSUnified/Extensions/ViewExtensions.cs) too.