# Xamarin Forms android webview input disappears behind keyboard

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

I have an issue with the keyboard appearing over the contents of a webview in a Xamarin.Forms. When I have a webview containing an `<input type="text" />` at the bottom of the page, and I focus it, the keyboard appears over the input, and I have no way of scrolling the input into view. So I have no way to view what I am typing in the input.

The issue only occurs in the android version of the app, the iOS version of the app resizes correctly.

I've searched the internet and found several people stating that you should set the `WindowSoftInputMode` property to `AdjustResize`. I've tried this, to no avail. Other solutions contain a lot of android specific code, with mixed reactions to it working or not. None of these solutions seem to work.

I found a few things that cause the issue:

- Once I set `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(this, Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);` to avoid showing the title bar, the issue starts occurring
- Once I set the mainpage to a `FlyOutPage` (which used to be called master-detail page) the issue starts occurring.

This means that if I remove the `SetTitleBarVisibility` call, and remove the flyout page, the scrolling works correctly. However, especially the second one breaks my app.

I've created a really simple test project demonstrating the issue.

Android example (this is the issue):

[image]

iOS example (this works correctly out of the box):

[image]

Code:

App.Xaml:

```cs
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AndroidSpecific.Application.SetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this, AndroidSpecific.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
            //MainPage = new MainPage();
            MainPage = new FlyOut(); //this flyout is issue reason 1
        }
```

flyout.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.FlyOut"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:App1">
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <pages:FlyOutFlyout x:Name="FlyoutPage" />
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MainPage></pages:MainPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="webview" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

webview html source:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:50px; height: 600px;"></div>
    <input type="text" />
  </body>
</html>
```

android mainactivity:

```cs
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize, WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            //this is culprit number 2:
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(this, Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to make the Android version behave in a similar way as iOS? The goal here is to make changes to the xamarin app to make it behave correctly with the given html, not to change the html to make it work in android.

Comment: Have you tested on an actual phone? The emulator might behave incorrectly in some situations, because there is a physical keyboard on pc, but soft keyboard is being emulated.

Comment: You might be able to adapt the custom renderer in this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273431/199364.

Comment: Yes I have tested it on an actual phone. The custom renderer link you refer to is an ios specific renderer. My issue is not with ios but with Android

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to OnCreate method of the MainActivity after LoadApplication.

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

This is my OnCreate method, and it works correctly.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(this, Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
    }
```

Comment: I have already done this (as I stated in the question), but this doesn't seem to work when your main page is a flyout page, and also not when you have set the global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(this, Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never)

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more detailed. In addition, I also used the flyoutpage as the maipage and set the global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(this, Xamarin.Forms.AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never). It works correctly on my device just need to wait a second when you tap the inputview. I don't know why the same code doesn't work on yor device. I do this according to the [link](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/). It may give you some ideas.@PaulVrugt

Comment: I have attached a test project in which my issue can be reproduced in the issue I posted at: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15021

Comment: In the project, you still don't add the code I provide. I had tried the way to set the WindowSoftInputMode you used. It didn't work and so I used the code I provide. Did you really try to add the code I provided in your OnCreate method after 'LoadApplication(new App())'?@PaulVrugt

Comment: TBH, I saw yet another suggestion about setting the SoftInputMode and assumed it was the same as the other ones. I now see that you suggestion sets the SoftInputMode in a different way. However, unfortunately setting it your way leads to the same result. It only works if I don't use a flyout page, and don't set the titlebarvisibility. You can reproduce it using the same reproduction app as in the xamarin.forms issue

Comment: I had test your project on my device. When I add the code I had provided, it works correctly. So I can't understand why it doesn't work on your device.@PaulVrugt

Comment: I don't understand the difference either. I've tested it on several different physical devices and an emulator, but none work. Could you maybe share the testproject I made with your modifications with me? Then I can test if you version works for me?

Comment: I have posted my project to the github. You can test it and this is the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/CSSClientAppsXamarinSampleCode/tree/main/WebViewInputTest). @PaulVrugt

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your project, but it doesn't seem to work. So I guess the issue might be specific to certain android devices. I've tried it on an Pixel 2 Android 10 emulator, a google nexus Android 10 physical device, and a samsung android 11 physical device. On all of these devices the input disappears behind the keyboard.

Comment: It's unbelievable. I had tried on the Pixel 4 Android 10 emulator. When I tap the inputview ,the inputview will be hidden by the keyboad at first and will show above the keyboard in an instant. @PaulVrugt